# Error when building a C++ program for the second time

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, mingw, mingw-w64

After some time I've got this problem with my C++ compiler.
When I write the code and I compile if for the first time, there's no problem and I can execute it normally. But then, **after the program is finished** in the terminal, if I make any change in the code and try to compile it again, I get this problem:

*c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\gabri\Codes/test.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status*

And I get access denied when trying to run the .exe file after that.
I have no idea how to solve it. I try to compile usually in Sublime but even in an IDE like Codeblocks I get the same problem.

[I don't know if it might help, but this is an image of my PC's Path, just in case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEhum.jpg)

Comment: Make certain you do not have an instance of the program running. For example, you might still have the debugger running.

Comment: Your program is still running. Kill it before updating the executable file.

Comment: How do I kill it? The execution of the program was already finished, apparently, how could I check if it's actually still running?
Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Paths suggest a windows PC. Open the Windows Task Manager. If Windows 8 or higher, click more details. Check the list of running tasks for your program. It may be hidden under the debugger's process, so expand it. A more versatile tool for this is [Sysinternal's Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). If the process is not running, Process Explorer can help you track down any other processes that may still have the executable locked.

Comment: Actually I believe the program is indeed finished. I searched everywhere and I couldn't find anything related. Even turning the computer off and on again I can't compile or have access to these programs. Before I could edit the program and compile it after the execution, which is natural, and with almost every program I make nowadays I have this problem.
And even if the process is still running somewhere else the I can't find, it would not me normal, it should finish normally after the execution.
Couldn't this mean another thing, other than that?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to compile even when the previous process is still running. You must track it from task manager and kill the process before you compile it again.

Looking into your comment,seems like a permission issue may be,check if you are running the command prompt or the IDE with admin privilege or not,if no,try running it with administrator privilege.

Comment: Actually I believe the program is indeed finished. I searched everywhere and I couldn't find anything related. Even turning the computer off and on again I can't compile or have access to these programs. Before I could edit the program and compile it after the execution, which is natural, and with almost every program I make nowadays I have this problem.
And even if the process is still running somewhere else the I can't find, it would not me normal, it should finish normally after the execution.
Couldn't this mean another thing, other than that?

Comment: @GabrielOliveiraMartins did it work? i mean the updated answer